# Where to shutdown actors

Tags: scala, akka

we have a lot of actors that get created as

```
class BankActor extends Actor{
   def receive ={
      case CreateCustomer(message) => context.actorOf(Props[CustomerActor]) ! message
  }
}
```

And CustomerActor creates other actors in a similar manner. Reason for creating actors in such a way is potentially there will be hundreds(or even thousands) of CreateCustomer messages that BankActor will be receiving in them. I thought creating them on the fly is a better way (given Actor is a low memory footprint). I didn't think having a "pool" of CustomerActor was a right thing to do because biz req is clear there will be lots and lots of "CreateCustomer" messages. can you share your thoughts on this? Now going back to question about stopping "CustomerActor" : where should I be doing context.stop(self) inside "CustomerActor"'s "receive" method, should it be the last thing in every "case" block in there? What's the best practice around this?

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to give any practical advice.

Comment: I'll echo Ryan here, to get useful response you need to give more information. Though one thing I'd say - the construct above creates an actor for every message you send, there might be a genuine reason for that, however if you just want to stop an actor after sending the message, then probably you need to rethink your design and try to reuse already created actors.

Comment: I have added a lot more details to the question now. let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid creating top-level actors unless you have a good reason to. (Use context.actorOf)

Send the newly created actor a PoisonPill after the "message" if you don't want to encode the shutdown within the created actor.

```
class BankActor extends Actor{
   def receive = {
      case CreateCustomer(message) =>
        val customer = context.actorOf(Props[CustomerActor])
        customer ! message
        customer ! PoisonPill // message ordering is preserved on a per-sender basis (for all normal mailboxes)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor. It was a genuine typo(literally was typing the snippet) in the example where actually I am using context.actorOf. Corrected it in the question. To send PoisonPill is following the right thing/way?case CreateCustomer(message) => 
        val customerActor = context.actorOf(Props[CustomerActor]) ! message
        customerActor ! PoisionPill
      }

Comment: Yes, exactly, I added a snippet to explain.